# How do I use Apple's Reachbility in conjunction with NSURLConnection or NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlconnection

Across my app I am using NSURLConnection to make any server related API Calls.

I am using the function `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest queue completionHandler` to make async requests to the server. Sometimes these requests fail because there is no internet connection.

How would I use Apple's Reachability Class in conjunction with NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do that:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];    
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {
    // connection ok: call NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest queue completionHandler here
}
else {
    // No connection
}
```

Be careful to check if the network is provided by wifi or not before download big data. You can check this through the internetStatus.

Comment: Not the right solution.  Reachability can get confused easily, and this will prevent you from making requests that would otherwise succeed.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know about possible confusion. Could you tell me more about this behavior please?

Comment: Sure.  Reachability periodically checks the network to see if it is working.  If those probes fail for whatever reason, whether a temporary DNS failure, packet loss, etc., it can report a failure even if a request would actually succeed.  Experimentally, reachability is most likely to lie to you when used over a cellular network, or when changing networks rapidly.  The usual symptom is that you see cell service or a Wi-Fi signal, and some apps can connect to the Internet, but others can't.  Of course, I don't know the precise cause.  If I did, I would file a bug, and it would be fixed already.

Comment: More precisely, when the cellular network is awful, you're more likely to see this.

Comment: Many thanks for this clarification, it's very interesting and it will change my way to check internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use reachability is as follows:

1. Make the request.
2. If it fails, create a reachability listener for the specific host that you're trying to reach (reachabilityWithHostName:).
3. When that class indicates that reachability has changed, check to see if it says that it is now reachable, and if so, dispose of the reachability object and re-issue the request.

What you absolutely should *not* do is gate the initial request on reachability.  The reachability APIs can get out of sync with reality, causing your app to fail to make requests that would otherwise have succeeded.

It is, however, acceptable to limit the *retry* rate of periodic requests based on overall reachability.  However, if any of those requests succeeds, your app should then act as though reachability gave it a green light even if it didn't.